# "Do you have a car?" or "Have you a car?"

Tags: have

While I use translate both translates are gives same result. I remember that I used before. But I heard this using is wrong. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["have" vs."have got" in American and British English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721/have-vs-have-got-in-american-and-british-english)

Comment: It's not exactly "wrong", but for most contexts, "Have you a car?" is hopelessly dated. Avoid it, in favour of either *Do you have a car?* or *Have you got a car?*

Comment: Okay, I get it. Do you think I should use it?

Comment: Like I said, ***avoid it**!*

Comment: Thanks. I understand.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's no *got* in the OP's Q though.

Comment: What? I can't understand @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.

Comment: Sorry, was a comment for FumbleF. Have edited the comment.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Your point is well made! I just took it for granted that with 35 upvotes, that earlier question must surely have covered all the relevant variations. But I've just gone through it with a fine-tooth comb (just a "find" in the browser, actually! :), and there's not a single mention of the "dated syntax" of questions like *Have you a light?* I may have to search again for a better duplicate (which I'm 100% certain ***will*** exist; it should be asked on ELL anyway, but it will have been asked repeatedly here before ELL even existed).

Comment: ...Crumbs! The best I can find so far is [Help me please..What need have you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445167/) Which has 5 answers, but *they've all been deleted, and none of them even have any upvotes*. But I had no problem finding [Use of “Have” in questions “Do you have” or “Have you”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101667/) on ELL. I've retracted my "duplicate" closevote, but that leaves me unable to ***re-vote*** to migrate to ELL.

Comment: I don't agree that 'have' without 'got' is 'hopelessly dated'.  Dated, yes.

Comment: I wouldn't say _Have you a light?_, not only because I don't smoke, but because I have an American accent. Anyone saying _Have you_ in a question instead of _Do you have_ should have a recognizably British accent, if they're not already in the UK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would be difficult to give a short good answer for that, because it's different for AmE and BrE and different for questions, negatives and question tags. So, I think you won't find "I haven't a clue" problematic, and "We still have the one in Cornwall to try, haven't we?" OK too. But, for example, "We have a good time, haven't we?" is a non-starter. It's complicated stuff!

Comment: @John Lawler: I don't smoke as of 6 months ago, so I would no longer be likely to ask for a light ***myself***, either. But I'd be somewhat conflicted if someone asked ***me*** "Have you a light?". As a fully paid-up member of ELU, I'd want to correct the (hopelessly?) dated phrasing, but as a recent quitter, I'd be falling over myself to say "No, I won't give you a light - if I can quit, so can you!".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Congratulations!  (I know what it's like)